# ASUS ROG B450-F motherboard QLED blinks in sequence and won't post

Tags: boot, motherboard, post

For some odd reason my computer won't post, the QLEDs on my ASUS ROG strix are stuck in a loop flashing in sequence and won't post. All the fans turn on. I removed all peripherals and is currently using one stick of RAM. I've also cleared the CMOS. All of the documentation based on the b450f revolve around the QLEDs staying one color and can't find any information anywhere else. The sequence in which the QLEDs flash is white, green, red. And it's stuck in that loop.

Hopefully someone here can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sequence? Are you saying that the sequence the lights present is not noted in the documentation?

Comment: @music2myear the sequence is white, green, red. And its stuck in that loop. Correct that sequence is not noted in the manual or anywhere.

Comment: That information needs to have been in the original question. It is information basic to the problem and so must be included there. Please use the EDIT button to add this.

Comment: @music2myear I added that to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you resolve @vslat ?
X470F board also not POSTING, mine is showing a sequence.

- BOOT (green)
- VGA (white)
- CPU (red)
- DRAM (yellow)

I get Yellow, Red, White - and repeats. Which indicates it got stuck on the VGA for me? Did you get any answers from support? This board booted with the same gfx adapter an hour ago before I moved it into the case, and I swapped the adapter for another, also not holding up to my theory about the LEDs sequencing. The only change is that I now have more fans attached now, going to unplug those and see if it resolves.

edit: Had to add washers under all of the standoffs to raise the standoffs, by about 1mm, to resolve the graphics card not seating far enough down to make good contact.

I know this does not answer the original question, which remains open as I write. Hope it helps.

Comment: So you can now delete your comments. I’ve flagged them for removal as they are now redundant